# Treeview Css problem

Tags: asp.net

Im using asp.net treeview in my apllication.i have apply css class for selecte node of treeview
.MyNavTreeSelected
{
background-color:Gray; 
}

when i run the page first time last node of my treeview automatically set that background color  as i applied in css.....and if i select any node of my treeview as soon as my css has worked but after page post back it just disapper...how do i maintain that css after postback...     and
last node of my treeview defaultly set css....

how can i avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling this has something to do with the :visited CSS property. Basically, your browser remberber that you have clicked the node, and apply the default CSS for that node.

Take a look at the SelectedNodeStyle property.

Comment: im my selected node style property i given
  <SelectedNodeStyle  CssClass="MyNavTreeSelected" />
so after page redirecting i couldnt maintain css

Comment: how do i check css propert defaultly set in last node of treeview?